# Visual Studio Community 2015 To VSC 2017

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I plan to upgrade my `VSC2015` to `VSC2017` . I'm familiarizing the IDE & using it for days now, unlike from `Android Studio` it is easy to upgrade.

From the `VSC2017` window the boxes are uncheck.

**Do I really need to re-install them? The SDK's? I already have this `SDK` from `VSC2015` .**

[image: vs]

Comment: I had the same thought when I updated to VS 2017. The Payload itself, **yes** , you need to Install. If SDK is already available, it will just use the same or update it based on VS 2017 Compatibility.

Comment: I thought I would install those back, but yes. It detected those SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to select the SDKs you would like to be available. During the next steps, the installer figures out if you already have an SDK installed, SDK installation no-ops and adds the references to the installed SDK telling VS2017 that the SDK is available.